# Why is ScreenToClient Function not working correctly?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, mouse-position

I am trying to create the main menu of a console application. And I wanted the user to click on a specific place to go to either the login or signup part. I have been trying for it to work but it isn't.

```
void Menu::Welcome() {

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD consoleMode;
    GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, &consoleMode);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle, FOREGROUND_BLUE|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tMuSicHub" << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle,FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    cout << "\t\t\t\tRecommending Songs Through User Behaviour" << endl;

...
    cursorpos.X = 45;
    cursorpos.Y = 10;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(consoleHandle, cursorpos);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE);

    cout << "Click ";

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle, FOREGROUND_BLUE);

    cout << "Here ";

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE);

    cout << "To Login!";

    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    POINT p;
    while (1) {
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd,&p);
        if (p.x > 51 && p.x < 56) {
            cout << "Login" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I added print statements after GetCursorPos and ScreenToClient and the values did not change at all? I was expecting for the value of p.x to be adjusted. But they weren't. Is there something that I am doing wrong? What do I do to correct this code.

Comment: One standard thing you should always do in WinApi programming, especially when troubleshooting, is to check the return values of the called WinApi functions for whether they succeeded. E.g. `if (!GetCursorPos(&p))` will help you to check for error in `GetCursorPos` (it returns `BOOL`). If the function fails, you can get more detailed information about the exact error with [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

Comment: As for your actual problem, one thing is that you seem to assume that `SetConsoleCursorPosition` sets the same kind of "position" you then check using `p.x`. But the former sets cursor position *in characters*, while `p.x` is in pixels. So, `Here` begins not at x position 52 as you seem to assume, but at 52-nd character position on its row. That's why it probably "doesn't work". As for translating coordinates, it may leave `p.x` the same depending on the window position (if it's left edge is on the edge of the screen), so this may be not an actual error.

Comment: `GetConsoleWindow()` was a mistake. It should have never been invented. What it does largely depends on what your console's host is. If you need mouse input in your console you should request it (`SetConsoleMode`) and then read it (`ReadConsoleInput`).

Comment: Check also DPI issues.

Comment: It works in a clean console project but the meaning is unclear to call `ScreenToClient` with `GetConsoleWindow`.